# How to make a multiple row result set into one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a little trouble with this query.

**As a disclaimer, I know a While Loop is not exactly the best approach here but for my purposes, I have to use it. I know I can directly insert by explicitly putting the column names.**

Anyway, the goal of the query is to insert a value into a temporary table, one-by-one.

The table should look like this at the end:

```
Score GameId DateOfReview TitleOfReview                DescriptionOfReview
 98     1      11/11/11    "Skyrim : A Masterpiece" "The best open world game."
```

But my table looks like this:

```
Score GameId DateOfReview TitleOfReivew DescriptionOfReview
 98    98       98            98              98
  1     1        1             1              1
11/11/11 11/11/11 11/11/11   11/11/11       11/11/11
 "Skyrim : A Masterpiece "Skyrim : A Masterpiece "Skyrim : A Masterpiece "Skyrim : A Masterpiece "Skyrim : A Masterpiece
 "The best open world game." "The best open world game." "The best open world game." "The best open world game." "The best open world game."
```

I am very sure that my problem is in my While Loop. Again, I know this isn't the best way to do this, but I am not trying to explicitly put column names in the 
    VALUES

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<review><score>98</score><gameid>1</gameid><dateofreview>11/11/11</dateofreview><titleofreview>Skyrim : A Masterpeice</titleofreview><descriptionofreview>The best open world game.</descriptionofreview></review>';
DECLARE @dataCount int, @currentGameIndex int;
DECLARE @outputTable TABLE (Score nvarchar(max), GameId nvarchar(max), Date nvarchar(max), Title nvarchar(max), Description nvarchar(max));

SET @dataCount = @xml.query('count(/review/*)').value('.', 'int');
SET @currentGameIndex = 1;

WHILE @currentGameIndex <= @dataCount
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @outputTable
VALUES

 @xml.query('/node()[1]/node()[sql:variable("@currentGameIndex")]/node()[1]').value('.', 'varchar(max)'), @xml.query('/node()[1]/node()[sql:variable("@currentGameIndex")]/node()[1]').value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 
 @xml.query('/node()[1]/node()[sql:variable("@currentGameIndex")]/node()[1]').value('.', 'varchar(max)'),  @xml.query('/node()[1]/node()[sql:variable("@currentGameIndex")]/node()[1]').value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 
 @xml.query('/node()[1]/node()[sql:variable("@currentGameIndex")]/node()[1]').value('.', 'varchar(max)')
SET @currentGameIndex = @currentGameIndex + 1;
END

SELECT * FROM @outputTable;
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't use plain SQL query via @xml.nodes?

Comment: @Tyron78 I don't want to explicitly put the XML data in. As long as there's an XML attribute, I want to keep looping.

Comment: But this would require the number of destination columns to be dynamic!? Currently - in cour code - you mess up the GameID with the Data ID. You loop over the XML Data and create a row with 5 times (the number of your destination columns) the same value... so in short: THIS can not be used as insert. You would have to define the variables per attribute, populate them in your loop and then insert them. Furthermore: your code is lacking the "GameIndex + 1" and more important the differentiation between GameID and DataID.

Comment: Is there a way to do accomplish this without an INSERT then? Thank you for the edit recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a solution using the XML nodes, but without hardcoded column names. However, this might work on rather short XML variables, but I'm not sure about huge XML strings. Anyways, if your data is stored in a table rather than in a Variable, simply replace the variable @xnl with the table name.

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<review><score>98</score><gameid>1</gameid><dateofreview>11/11/11</dateofreview><titleofreview>Skyrim : A Masterpeice</titleofreview><descriptionofreview>The best open world game.</descriptionofreview></review>';
DECLARE @GetNodes NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT NodeName = 'T.C.value(' + CHAR(39) + '(' + C.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)') + ')[1]' + CHAR(39) + ', ' + CHAR(39) + 'nvarchar(100)' + CHAR(39) + ') AS [' + C.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)') + ']'
    FROM @xml.nodes('/review/*') AS T(C)
    )
SELECT @GetNodes = 'DECLARE @xml XML = ' + CHAR(39) + CAST(@xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + CHAR(39) + ';
                    SELECT ' + STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + NodeName
            FROM cte
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') + ' FROM @xml.nodes(' + CHAR(39) + 'review' + CHAR(39) + ') T(C)'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @GetNodes
```

Comment: The ctes purpose here is simply to make the code a bit more readable. You could replace it with a subquery as well. The interesting part here is the concatination of the node names in order to use them in the query statement.

Comment: Thank you, this is quite nice.